# How to create a Doughnut chart in django admin interface using foreign key field data?

Tags: django, django-admin, chart.js

I am working on creating a Django admin interface, wherein i am plotting in three doughnut charts to visualize the data but out of three charts only one charts is working correctly. What i think the problem is that the other two charts are using the data of foreign key field and i am not sure how to make the call for the data.  Kindly help me to modify the code for the charts, the help will be highly appreciated. Following is code for my model.py, admin.py and template for creating the interface.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


AGREEMENT_TYPE = (
    ('MOU', 'MOU'),
    ('MOA', 'MOA'),
    ('Research Collaboration Agreement', 'Research Collaboration Agreement'),
    ('Research Grant Agreement', 'Research Grant Agreement'),
    ('Miscellaneous Agreements', 'Miscellaneous Agreements'),
    ('Collaboration Agreement (General/Various Collaboration)', 'Collaboration Agreement (General/Various Collaboration)'),
    ('Database Subscription Agreement', 'Database Subscription Agreement'), 
    ('Student Scholarship / Sponsorship Agreement', 'Student Scholarship / Sponsorship Agreement'),
    ('Clinical Trial Agreement (USM)', 'Clinical Trial Agreement (USM)'),
    ('Donation / Endowment Agreement', 'Donation / Endowment Agreement'),
    ('Students and Staff Exchange Agreement', 'Students and Staff Exchange Agreement'),
    ('Material Transfer Agreement', 'Material Transfer Agreement'),
    ('Non-Disclosure Agreement / Confidentiality', 'Non-Disclosure Agreement / Confidentiality'),
    ('Academic Programs (Dual Degree /  Joint Degree)', 'Academic Programs (Dual Degree /  Joint Degree)'),
    ('Services', 'Services'),
    ('Academic Collaborations / Exchanges Agreement', 'Academic Collaborations / Exchanges Agreement'),
    ('E-Book Publication / Licencing Agreement (PENERBIT USM)', 'E-Book Publication / Licencing Agreement (PENERBIT USM)'),
    ('Licensing and Commercialization', 'Licensing and Commercialization'),
    ('Off-Shore Program Agreement', 'Off-Shore Program Agreement'),
    ('Industrial Training / Internship Agreement', 'Industrial Training / Internship Agreement'),
    ('Industrial PHD Agreement', 'Industrial PHD Agreement'),
    ('Clinical Trial Agreement (USAINS)', 'Clinical Trial Agreement (USAINS)'),
)


class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField('Country', max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class Agreement_Type(models.Model):
    agreement_name = models.TextField('Agreement Type', choices=AGREEMENT_TYPE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agreement_name

class Agreement(models.Model):
    agreement_code = models.CharField('Agreement Code', max_length=10)
    agreement_type = models.ForeignKey(Agreement_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization_name = models.TextField('Organization Name')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_signing = models.DateField('Date Of Signing')
    date_of_expiry = models.DateField('Date Of Expiry')
    year = models.CharField('Year', max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agreement_code

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Agreement')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from InternationalRelations.models import Country
from InternationalRelations.models import Agreement_Type
from InternationalRelations.models import Agreement


class Agreement_TypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    save_on_top = True
    change_list_template = 'change_list_graph.html'

class AgreementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('agreement_code', 'agreement_type', 'organization_name', 'country', 'date_of_signing', 'date_of_expiry', 'year')
    list_filter = ('agreement_type', 'country', 'year')
    save_as = True
    save_on_top = True
    change_list_template = 'change_list_graph.html'



admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(Agreement_Type, Agreement_TypeAdmin)
admin.site.register(Agreement, AgreementAdmin)
```

change_list_graph.html(Template)

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var randomColorGenerator = function () {
            return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
        };
        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            }
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("agreement_type-chart");
            {% regroup cl.queryset|dictsort:"agreement_type" by get_agreement_type_display as agreement_type_list %}
            var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: [{% for agreement_type in agreement_type_list %}'{{ agreement_type.grouper }}',{% endfor %}],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [{% for agreement_type in agreement_type_list %}'{{ agreement_type.list|length }}',{% endfor %}],
                        backgroundColor: [{% for agreement_type in agreement_type_list %}randomColorGenerator(),{% endfor %}]
                    }]
                }, options: options
            });
            ctx = document.getElementById("country-chart");
            {% regroup cl.queryset|dictsort:"country" by country as country_list %}
            lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: [{% for country in country_list %}'{{ country.grouper }}',{% endfor %}],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [{% for country in country_list %}'{{ country.list|length }}',{% endfor %}],
                        backgroundColor: [{% for country in country_list %}randomColorGenerator(),{% endfor %}]
                    }]
                }, options: options
            });
            ctx = document.getElementById("year-chart");
            {% regroup cl.queryset|dictsort:"year" by year as year_list %}
            lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: [{% for year in year_list %}'{{ year.grouper }}',{% endfor %}],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [{% for year in year_list %}'{{ year.list|length }}',{% endfor %}],
                        backgroundColor: [{% for year in year_list %}randomColorGenerator(),{% endfor %}]
                    }]
                }, options: options
            });
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1> Graphs for IMCC Data </h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <canvas id="agreement_type-chart" style="width: 100px !important;"></canvas>
            <h4 align="center"><b> AGREEMENT DISTRIBUTION </b></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <canvas id="country-chart" style="width: 100px !important;"></canvas>
            <h4 align="center" color="green"><b> COUNTRY DISTRIBUTION </b></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <canvas id="year-chart" style="width: 100px !important;"></canvas>
            <h4 align="center" color="green"><b> YEARLY DISTRIBUTION </b></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide code in format instead of images

Comment: I have made the changes, kindly have a look @LinhNguyen.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure i am not giving the exact solution to your question. But i found [Django Jet](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) recently and i found it very interesting and easy to configure. With Jet, it is very easy to set a doughnut chart in the admin dashboard. Please ignore if you are not into it

Comment: Actually my Dashboard is already ready with the code above, it just that agreement_type-chart and country-chart does not show up, so i am trying to find a solution for that problem. Still thank you for informing me about Django Jet

Comment: Fine. I tried it for the first time today. That is why i informed it.